# android : replace x bytes in the beginning of a file with y bytes

Tags: android, file, replace, random-access

I want to replace first x bytes of a file with y bytes. That is x and y are NOT same length.
I tried copying to new file. Its working, but slow for large files. I know for exact length of replacement RAndomAccessfile can be used. But i am not able to use it for my purpose.

Thanks a lot for the your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `x` and `y` aren't the same, you have no choice but to write `y` and then write the remainder of the file, even if all you're doing is shifting the rest of the file up by `y - x` bytes.

Comment: i saw FileChannel . Is it not an option. Is there a reason why it is not recommended

Answer (score 2):

If you desperately need it to be fast, then you might create an own random access interface, backed by a set of immutable files + immutable changelists. If your application has some spare time, then it could merge the last immutable commit point + the changelist into a new file in the background.

A changelist can be as simple as

- path of previous changelist/commit point file
- offset and length to be replaced
- replacement data

A commit point is simply a whole file.

Comment: Its a good idea. but in my app i will not know in prior which files will have to be changed. I want to change it on the fly . Thank you very much

Comment: @preetha This can be applied on the fly.